# BinaryString to alpabetical representation

Tags: java

How would I go about convert a BinaryString to its alphabet representation
for example i have the number 88 --->1011000---->X
I have the the first two steps but am stuck on the last conversion from the binary to the X.

```
    String plain = "";
    int m = 0;
    int x = 2;
    for (int i = 0;i<(text.length()/2);i++)
    {
        standin = text.substring(m,x);
        if (standin.charAt(0) == '1')
        {
            x = (x++);
            standin = text.substring(m,x);
        }
        int binary = Integer.parseInt(standin);
        String bb = Integer.toBinaryString(binary);
        System.out.println(bb);

        x++;
        m++;
    }
```

bb's ouput is 1011000 if standin is 88.

Comment: Why convert to binary first? Why not just convert `88` to `'X'` directly, as in `int i = 88; char c = (char)i;`?

Comment: you can cast in this way?@Andreas

Comment: Works like a charm! thanks@Andreas

Comment: What is the purpose of that `charAt(0) == '1'` check? `x = (x++)` does exactly nothing. It takes the value of `x`, then increments `x`, then saves the original value back. Result: `x` is unchanged.

Comment: i am using it to determine if the digit is a three digit binary rep as it would be a 1 in the hundreds. from my understanding x++ will increment x by one and is the same as x = (x+1)@Andreas

Comment: And if you change it to `x++;`, the input `"123123412345"` will generate the following sequence of `standin` values: `"123"`, `"231"`, `"312"`, `"1234"`, `"2341"`, `"3412"`. The last `345` characters are never read.

Comment: i see so what i am getting from your above comment is that within the if statement i should be decrementing x again after using it to grab my three digit numbers@Andreas

Comment: No. The `x++; m++;` at the end should be `m = x; x = m + 2;`

Comment: Okay thanks I am going to have to think this through. But what you said works. Thanks again.@Andreas

Answer (score 0):

```
int parsed = Integer.parseInt(toParse, 2);
System.out.println(parsed);
```

Will parse a string that is a binary number. From there the rest of your problem is pretty simple. Just get the returned int as a string and you are done.

Comment: i am a little confused by your answer could you use it in my code? Not sure where i would implement this. I am pretty new to java.

Comment: There is literally nothing to it. Just take the string you want to parse, and call Integer.parseInt(myString, 2). The result will be a number that you can print out. See my edited answer.

Comment: This is actually the answer to your question... remember to flag the answer as the correct answer ;) Here is the documentation of `parseInt`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int) . Oh, and the last line to get the int->String: `parsed.toString()`